# using .htaccess to redirect from friendly url to actual file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following RewriteRule in my .htaccess to redirect from a friendly url to my main application file:

```
RewriteRule ^\/(.*).html$ home/www/page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

This should send any url that points to a html page to page.php with the url as a parameter that will be parsed by the app.
This works for urls that look like http://www.example.com/hello.html

The problem is that I get a 404 error when the url contains a directory path, for example: http://www.example.com/category/hello.html

The error reads: "File does not exist: /home/www/category"

Seems it is first looking for the 'category' path instead of processing the .htaccess
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the initial `\/` from your rewrite rule?

I just tried the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

With this as my `page.php`:

```
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
```

And when I go to [`/category/hello.html`](http://localhost/category/hello.html) I get the following:

```
Array ( [p] => category/hello )
```

Exactly as expected.

Also note that you need to escape the `.` before `html`, since you presumably don't want [`/category/hellozhtml`](http://localhost/category/hellozhtml) to work.